# Window.print() -> save as pdf in just one click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, pdf

I need to print a modal that contains a table as a pdf. The requirement is that if user clicks on the button named **Save pdf**, the table will be converted into a pdf and be saved. I have tried **JsPDF** and **html2pdf** but these plugins do not allow custom CSS, so they do not resemble the same table. One solution was to write a print screen code where I can append desired HTML and CSS but there is this extra step of selecting PDF and clicking on the print button. Is there any way I can bypass these steps and just get the file downloaded after a click?